# Xubuntu on an old laptop can't connect to internet

Tags: networking, xubuntu, lubuntu, internet

I have an old laptop HP Compaq nx 7400  which used to run Lubuntu 15.10. Wired and WiFi worked fine. Then I changed to Xubuntu 15.10, which actually feels quicker on my laptop than Lubuntu. But the problem is, I can't connect to internet anymore, neither wired nor WiFi. Wired worked during LiveCD mode, where you can try Xubuntu without installing and also during installation it had a connection. But after the installation was done and after rebooting, it couldn't connect anymore. I even tried reinstalling, but it was the same.

What should I do? I really like Xubuntu and I hope we can figure this out and I don't have go back to Lubuntu.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Kubuntu, Cubuntu, etc ... it's more a matter of eyecandy and personal taste. They all are sharing the same base (same Ubuntu underneath).
Install Lubuntu back (because it worked) and install the 'xubuntu-desktop' in it by using the Software Center. Log out and log back in, this time using xubuntu desktop. Check out your internet connection.

After xubuntu-desktop is installed, you can uninstall 'lubuntu-desktop' by using Software Center. Make sure you always have at least one desktop environment installed at any given time, otherwise you'll be presented with just a black screen with simple text in it, namely a command-line (CLI) environment.